# Python openCV get VideoCapture from webRTC janus

Tags: python, webrtc, janus

In openCV `cv2.VideoCapture()`, I want receive video stream from webRTC server
Only Janus webRTC of node.js is available.

How can it be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use GStreamer for that.

`cv2.VideoCapture()` accepts a GStreamer pipeline, so you can use the `webrtcbin` and `appsink` plugins combined to receive a stream from any WebRTC client (including Janus).

Check out these links for guidance on how to do so:

https://answers.opencv.org/question/202017/how-to-use-gstreamer-pipeline-in-opencv/
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=python
https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/init.html?gi-language=python